# Get computer to mount Android phone at root directory

Tags: mount, 7.0-nougat

I have noticed that whenever I plug my phone into a computer through USB, it gets mounted at `/storage/emulated/0`. Is there a way I can get it to mount at `/`? I am running Resurrection Remix (7.1.1) with root.

Thanks

Comment: @GokulNC Yes. I said "I am running Resurrection Remix (7.1.1) **with root.**"

Comment: Oops, didn't see that.. Cleaned it up

Comment: Why do you want to do that BTW? Any specific reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Android can't be just mounted?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/why-android-cant-be-just-mounted)

Comment: _/storage/emulated/0_ is used as the mount point for the external storage (actually, internal storage which is mounted as external storage through kernel FUSE). _/_ is the mount point for the root filesystem. I don't think you can modify this behavior even if you have root privileges.